# How jQuery can prevent showing HTML element title even if it has title attribute in its tag?

Tags: jquery, attributes, title

I have a link like the below one, and I want to prevent showing it's title attribute on mouse over event. But I must keep it and I can not remove it.

```
<a href="" title="This is a test">Test</a>
```

How can I do it using jQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many times, accidentally I found a link that solves the problem. So I decided to put it here ...
Thanks for its writer

http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/

**HTML**:

```
<a class="fancybox" caption="This is 1st title" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="fancybox" caption="This is 2nd title" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's nice. Perhaps people should think in using something like data-caption instead of attribute "caption" that i think is not standard. data atributes are allowed in HTML5.

Comment: Nice work Mohammed.  And I agree with @tomasofen, and I did try his suggestion.  I simply changed "caption" to "data-caption" in the HTML.  And in the JQuery, changed ('caption') to ('data-caption').  Worked like a charm and no more tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few hacks on Stack Overflow (disable tooltip, suppress tooltip). I think this is the cleanest and it doesn't need jQuery:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/457382/1325290

```
// Suppress tooltip display for links that have the classname 'suppress'
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].className == 'suppress') {
        links[i]._title = links[i].title;
        links[i].onmouseover = function() { 
            this.title = '';
        }
        links[i].onmouseout = function() { 
            this.title = this._title;
        }
    }
}
```

Leave out the if...suppress part if you don't want it.

Comment: This function worked, but removed title from the link. The problem I have is that I'm using Fancybox. I need to show titles beside the opened thumbnail, but I don't like to see any title when mouseover event is occurred.

Comment: Can you try re-adding title with  `links[i].onclick = function() {this.title = this._title;}` ? So that right before the thumbnail opens the title is there? Alternatively you might get it to work with jQuery data as shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7296899/1325290

Comment: This approach is outdated - please see my reply below for a better way to do this with modern jQuery, which also works for elements created/loaded after the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I have - is prevent mouseover event form being trigger. Posiibly this solution will work:

```
$("a[title='Titlte is a test']").mouseover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If this will not help you then you can hack this with some opacity element placed over you a element - this actually will do the same - mouseover evenet wouldn't be tiggered. Note: you shoukd trigger click event on link when it will be catcjed on opacity element:

```
$("Opacity element id").click(function(e) {
    $("a[title='Titlte is a test']").click()
});
```

And similarly with mousedown/up events if they are used

Comment: which might be a security issue: not all browsers allow a redirect of `click` events on all tags :)

Comment: @Andreas,Never encounter this issue. Actually I know nothing about such secure problem. What are they intended for? If you word are right then we shouldn't use any jQuery triggering possibility'es as they are potentially not save

Comment: I attempted preventDefault() in Chrome, and it does not seem to suppress tooltips - I think tooltips are generated by browser-internal events/handlers that are not exposed to JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

The technique is to hide the title on mouseove and restore in on mouseout.

```
$("a#test").mouseover( function(e){

    var myLink = $('a#test');

    myLink.hover(
        function() {  
            old_title = $(this).attr('title');      
            $(this).attr('title',''); 
        },
        function() {  
            $(this).attr('title', old_title);  
        }  
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using modern jQuery:

```
jQuery(document.body)
  .on('mouseover', 'a[title]', null, function(event) {
    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
  })
  .on('mouseout', 'a[data-title]', null, function(event) {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title')).removeAttr('data-title');
  });
```

This handles all existing and future a-tags on the page, and causes very minimal memory-overhead, because it creates only a single pair of event-handlers for all elements - on hover, it moves the value from the `title` attribute to a `data-title` attribute, which it removes again when the mouse leaves the element.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I didn't care what the content of the title tag was so this was cleaner for me. I just did:

```
$('a').hover(function() {

    $(this).attr('title', '');

});
```

Which stopped the title tag from showing.