# Disable title tag in dc.js charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, title, dc.js

In [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/5no3898s/), built using [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js) we have got both [d3.tip](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/) as well as, default `title` tag.

We needed to have multiple data (not only `key` and `value`) in tooltip. For this reason, we're reducing the data:

```
 var denialGroup = denialReasonDim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
      p.reason = v.reason;
      p.payer = v.payer;
      p.denialAmount += v.denialAmount;
      p.claimCount += v.claimCount;
      ++p.count;
      return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
      p.reason = v.reason;
      p.payer = v.payer;
      p.denialAmount -= v.denialAmount;
      p.claimCount -= v.claimCount;
      --p.count;
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return {
        reason: '',
        payer: '',
        denialAmount: 0,
        claimCount: 0,
        count: 0
      }
    }
  );
```

And giving it to the rendering `title` tags:

```
.title(function(d) {
  var data = denialGroup.all().filter(function(t) {
    return t.key == d.data.key || t.value.reason == d.data.key;
  })
  return d.data.key +
    "\nDenial Amount: $" + formatNumber(d.value);

  if (data.length > 0) {
    return "Key: " + d.data.key +
      "\nValue Denial Amount : $" + formatNumber(d.value) +
      "\nClaim Count: " + formatNumber(data[0].value.claimCount) +
      "\nDenial Amount: $" + formatNumber(data[0].value.denialAmount);
  } else {
    return "Key: " + d.data.key +
      "\nValue Denial Amount : $" + formatNumber(d.value);
  }
});
```

And this data is being used by `d3.tip`:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {

      var tooltipText = $(this).find("title").text();
      var tooltipTexts = tooltipText.split('\n');
      var totalTips = tooltipTexts.length;
      var tooltipHtml = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < totalTips; i++) {
        var tipElements = tooltipTexts[i].split(':');
        var tipKey = tipElements[0];
        var tipValue = tipElements[1];
        tooltipHtml += "<div><strong>" + tipKey + "</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + tipValue + "</span></div>";
      }
      return tooltipHtml;
      /*return "<strong>" + d.key + "</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + "</span>";*/
    })
```

The problem is that our client doesn't like default browser `title` along with `d3-tip`. We're just interested in `d3-tip`, not default `title` tag

> Notice that it's not HTML's title attribute which can be disabled with [`e.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725162/2404470)

Comment: Why not just calculate the text inside the d3.tip `html` function? There's no particular reason that code has to be in `title`. Then there's [`.renderTitle(false)`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+renderTitle) to remove the title elements.

Comment: @Gordon Okey, however where shall I store the extra data? I don't need only the `key` and `value`, hence used the `reduce`

Comment: ? I don't see any extra data being stored here. You should be able to move the code without any problems. `denialGroup` is independent and can be used from `d3-tip` just as well as `.title`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but important question from an aesthetic perspective. You can simply return an empty string and modern browsers won't show the default tip from title tags:

```
.title(d => '')
```